# Transaction handling with JDBC Connection Pooling in Tomcat7

Tags: jsf, jdbc, transactions, db2, connection-pooling

I am developing a JSF application which uses JNDI connection pooling to a DB2 database through the Tomcat 7 configuration. I am having problems managing transactions and more specifically rolling back when an exception is thrown from a method which shares a connection.

The following code establishes a connection and passes this down through all other methods being called. This connection is then only closed in the finally block of the method. My issue is that for example...if an exception is thrown at any point in the method, any work completed prior to this is committed and not rolled back.  I was under the impression that when closing a connection in the finally block, this would not commit if any exceptions were thrown during the life time of this connection and then the connection is returned to the pool regardless if the work has been committed or rolled back.

```
public boolean updateSubCountry(SubCountryDTO dto,
        List<FeatureAliasDTO> aliases, List<FeatureCodeDTO> codes)
        throws ReferenceDataException {
    boolean success = true;
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        c = fDao.getConnection();
        success = fDao.updateSubCountry(c, dto, TEMP_USERNAME) && success;
        success = updateAliases(c, aliases, dto.getOdi(), TEMP_USERNAME,
                dto.getSubCountryId()) && success;
        for (FeatureCodeDTO codeDto : codes) {
            success = updateFeatureCode(c, codeDto, dto.getSubCountryId())
                    && success;
        }
    } finally {
        closeConnection(c, DEFAULT_CONNECTION_ERROR_MSG);
    }
    return success;
}
```

My JNDI configuration is as follows (sensitive info starred out):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/core" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         url="****"
         driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
         username="****" password="****"
         maxActive="20" maxIdle="3" maxWait="10000"
         poolPreparedStatements="true"
         maxOpenPreparedStatements="100"
         validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have attempted to implement the suggestions made by @Tiny. However, the when purposely making updateFeatureCode() method throw an exception on the database level, any work before this is still not rolled back?

```
@Transactional (rollbackFor={Exception.class, ReferenceDataException.class})
    public boolean updateSubCountry(SubCountryDTO dto,
            List<FeatureAliasDTO> aliases, List<FeatureCodeDTO> codes)
            throws ReferenceDataException {
        boolean success = true;
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = fDao.getConnection();
            success = fDao.updateSubCountry(c, dto, TEMP_USERNAME) && success;
            success = updateAliases(c, aliases, dto.getOdi(), TEMP_USERNAME,
                    dto.getSubCountryId()) && success;
            for (FeatureCodeDTO codeDto : codes) {
                success = updateFeatureCode(c, codeDto, dto.getSubCountryId())
                        && success;
            }
        } finally {
            closeConnection(c, DEFAULT_CONNECTION_ERROR_MSG);
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: "*I was under the impression that when closing a connection in the finally block, this would not commit if any exceptions were thrown during the life time of this connection and the connection is returned to the pool.*" Nope. You need to wrap your code around a transactional unit. If any exception occurs within that unit, the work done inside the transactional unit will be reverted/rolled back.

Comment: Right okay, what would be the best way of doing this? Would it be setting auto commit to false for the particular shared connection and the directly calling rollback() and commit() off of the connection object manually?

Comment: Setting auto-commit to false for a shared connection should be seldom needed but it depends. The best way, however, is to delegate this critical task to a transaction management system of your interest (declarative) such as EJBs (JTA) or Spring services designated with the `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation.

Comment: I managed to achieve the required behaviour by manual setting auto commit to false for the shared connection and then only committing if no exceptions were thrown. Ideally I would like to try and use the transaction management as mentioned.... I have updated my above  question to show what I have tried. I have include the spring dependency in my pom.xml to bring the spring api into my project. I included the @transactional tag to the service method, however nothing seems to change and the transaction does not work? Do I need to set up any other configurations in my JSF project? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The IBM JDBC driver, when connected to a DB2 database, defaults to `autoCommit=true`, which means that an explicit `COMMIT` is issued after each statement. If you wish to control transactions yourself, disable autocommit and commit or rollback as necessary. Alternatively, as suggested by @Tiny, use a transaction manager.

Comment: I have attempted to use the transaction manager (please see updated post). Could you explain how to implement this correctly please?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not versed in J2EE well enough to offer much help here.